# Why can not I see the this.tabPage1.Controls [K] .checked property?

Tags: c#

In the C # designer prepared in a form of a textbox, checkbox ... etc. objects. I want adjusted the value of a checkbox. Why can not I see the `this.tabPage1.Controls[K].Checked` property? When `this.tabPage1.Controls[K] .Name` or `this.tabPage1.Controls[K].Text` - properties accessible! 
I do not understand?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you might have to parse the control first.

```
((CheckBox) this.tabPage1.Controls[K]).Checked
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much :-) !
But I do not understand why it works?

Comment: That's because the controls are saved as the base type so every item can be saved. Then you have to parse the item to the subtype to access its specific properties

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I understand! :-)